How to replace completelly WooCommerce archive/category/tag product loop with my own?
In WooCommerce, I want to replace the default product loop by my own.
This is my code so far:
<?php
//make theme support woocommerce 
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_add_woocommerce_support');
function custom_theme_add_woocommerce_support()
{
    add_theme_support('woocommerce', array(
        'thumbnail_image_width' => 200,
        'single_image_width'    => 500,
    ));
    add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-zoom');
    add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-lightbox');
    add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-slider');
}

// Remove the default product loop
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );

// Remove the default product loop content
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 40 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_product_loop_end', 40 );

// Remove the woocommerce_shop_loop action
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product', 10 );

// Add your own custom loop
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_custom_product_loop_start', 40 );
function my_custom_product_loop_start() {
    // Your custom loop start code here
    // For example:
    echo '<div class="my-custom-loop">';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'my_custom_product_loop_end', 40 );
function my_custom_product_loop_end() {
    // Your custom loop end code here
    // For example:
    echo '</div>';
}

// Add your own custom product loop content
function my_custom_product_loop() {
    // Your custom product loop content code here
    // For example:
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        // Your custom product loop item code here
        // For example:
        echo '<div class="my-custom-product-loop-item">';
        echo '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
        echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

// Call the custom product loop function
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_custom_product_loop', 50 );


This function creates a new product loop, but the default loop isn't completely removed. Instead, it's being moved to the my-custom-loop div.
How can I completely replace WooCommerce original loop, with my own?
Also, will my custom loop work on related products within category and tag templates?

I kindly remember you that the rule on stack overflow is one question at the time.

Remove All Default Product Loop Actions
// Remove the default WooCommerce product loop
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );

// Remove the default product loop start/end and product rendering
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 40 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_product_loop_end', 40 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );

Add Your Custom Product Loop
// Add your own custom loop start
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_custom_product_loop_start', 40 );
function my_custom_product_loop_start() {
    echo '<div class="my-custom-loop">';
}

// Add your own custom loop content (products)
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'my_custom_product_loop', 50 );
function my_custom_product_loop() {
    // Your custom product loop content code here
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<div class="my-custom-product-loop-item">';
            echo '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
            echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
            echo '<div class="price">' . wc_get_template( 'loop/price.php' ) . '</div>'; // Output WooCommerce price template
            echo '<div class="add-to-cart">' . do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="' . get_the_ID() . '"]') . '</div>'; // Add to cart button
            echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo '<p>No products found</p>';
    }
}

// Add your own custom loop end
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'my_custom_product_loop_end', 40 );
function my_custom_product_loop_end() {
    echo '</div>'; // Close custom loop div
}

Related Products and Compatibility with Tags and Categories
// Remove WooCommerce related products loop and replace with custom one
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_related_products', 20 );

function my_custom_related_products() {
    // Custom related products loop
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 4, // Adjust the number of related products
        'orderby' => 'rand'    // You can customize the query as per your need
    );
    $related_products = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $related_products->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<div class="my-custom-related-products">';
        while ( $related_products->have_posts() ) : $related_products->the_post();
            echo '<div class="my-custom-related-product-item">';
            echo '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
            echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
            echo '<div class="price">' . wc_get_template( 'loop/price.php' ) . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="add-to-cart">' . do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="' . get_the_ID() . '"]') . '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}


your first part codes "Remove All Default Product Loop Actions" dosen't remove product list the ul, li, a and img tag still shows.
your second part works good but it returns all products in categories and tags
your third part code doesn't even return anything
